# Jaxb unmarshalling, list of every element is wrapped

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

This xml have a wrapper of whole list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <listWrapper>
    <box>
      <number>1</number>
    </box>
    <box>
      <number>2</number>
    </box>
    <box>
      <number>3</number>
    </box>
  </listWrapper>
</root>
```

and we can read like this:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "listWrapper")
@XmlElement(name = "box")
List<Box> boxList;
```

and describe Box class with "box" as root element

But how i can make the same list if i have wrapped each box instead all of?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <wrapper>
    <box>
      <number>1</number>
    </box>
  </wrapper>
  <wrapper>
    <box>
      <number>2</number>
    </box>
  </wrapper>
  <wrapper>
    <box>
      <number>3</number>
    </box>
  </wrapper>
</root>
```

In the end i want to list of box without wrapper level.

Comment: I apologize for the previous bad example, i edited it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The root class (main method to test mapping):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {


    private List<Wrapper> wrappers = new ArrayList<Wrapper>();  

    public Root(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();

        Wrapper wrapper1 = new Wrapper(new Box(1));
        root.getWrappers().add(wrapper1);

        Wrapper wrapper2 = new Wrapper(new Box(2));
        root.getWrappers().add(wrapper2);

        Wrapper wrapper3 = new Wrapper(new Box(3));
        root.getWrappers().add(wrapper3);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }


    @XmlElement(name = "wrapper")
    public List<Wrapper> getWrappers() {
        return wrappers;
    } 
    public void setWrappers(List<Wrapper> wrappers) {
        this.wrappers = wrappers;
    }

}
```

Wrapper class which contains Box:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Wrapper {

    private Box box;

    public Wrapper(){

    }

    public Wrapper(Box box){
        this.box = box;
    }   

    public Box getBox() {
        return box;
    }
    public void setBox(Box box) {
        this.box = box;
    }

}
```

Finally, Box class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Box {

    private Integer number;

    public Box(){

    }

    public Box(Integer number){
        this.number = number;
    }   

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made all right, but i need unmarshalling and make list of box and drop wrappers.